# Ad mananger is disturbing language strings in arabic but everything works fine in english

Tags: android, locale, arabic-support, google-ad-manager

I am using Google Ad Manager's native ads in android everything was working fine but then my app's arabic support is disturbed after the ads load.
This is my implementation of Admanager

```
public void createAd(boolean isAdManagerEnabled) {
        if (isAdManagerEnabled) {
            adLoader = new AdLoader.Builder(appManager.getContext(), AdManagerConstantsBase.CUSTOM_AD_UINT_ID)
                    .forCustomTemplateAd(AdManagerConstantsBase.CUSTOM_AD_TEMPLETE_ID, new NativeCustomTemplateAd.OnCustomTemplateAdLoadedListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCustomTemplateAdLoaded(NativeCustomTemplateAd nativeCustomTemplateAd) {
                            nativeCustomTemplateAd.recordImpression();
                            AdModel adModel = new AdModel();
                            addDataToAdModel(adModel, nativeCustomTemplateAd);
                            nativeAds.getValue().add(adModel);
                        }
                    }, null)
                    .withAdListener(new AdListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onAdFailedToLoad(LoadAdError adError) {
                            Logger.e("OnAddErrorCode", adError.getCode() + "");
                            Logger.e("OnAddErrorMessage", adError.getMessage() + "");
                        }
                    })
                    .build();

        }
```

And this was printed in the logs

```
Accessing hidden method Landroid/os/LocaleList;->setDefault(Landroid/os/LocaleList;I)V (greylist, linking, allowed)
2020-12-07 01:25:20.143 27270-27270 W/.: Accessing hidden method Landroid/os/LocaleList;-><init>(Ljava/util/Locale;Landroid/os/LocaleList;)V (greylist-max-o, linking, denied)
```

Apart from this is the library

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:19.3.0'
```

Language works fine in English. But gets ruined in Arabic just after the ads load

Comment: It will load automatically. Wait for it one or two days.

Comment: but they were loading before.
And I can still see them in debug build.

Comment: Give Testing Device Id to check it in your device.

Comment: I have done that too.